# How to mock a domain object ignoring validation when testing in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class which belongs to two other domain classes with several validations.

Lets say domain class Book belongs to Author. When testing the Book domain class, I want to simply have access to an Author object without having to create it with all the complex validations for Author. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

While saving the instance of `Author`, simply pass the `validate: false`.

```
Author authorInstance = new Author()
authorInstance.save(validate: false)
```

This will prevent validation at Grails level but not sure how this will behave when written to the database level.

Comment: It'll throw an exception if constraints are violated at the database layer

Comment: The build-test-data plugin is probably what I am after as answered by Donal below.

Answer (score 0):

The [build-test-data plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) is a great solution for this problem, it allows you to create/save a domain object specifying values only for the properties that you care about. The plugin will take care of filling in values for any other required properties/objects. For example if a book requires an author, title and ISBN, but your test is only concerned about the book title you can simply write

```
def book = Book.build(title: 'Great Expectations')
```

The plugin will take care of creating valid values for the ISBN and author and saving everything to the database.